# Show user exact or approximate location n google maps in asp.net c# in web site

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, compass-geolocation, ip-geolocation

I want to show user current location or approximate location on google maps in my web site using asp.net c#.Is it possible??? If it is kindly help me.I saw many tutorials but fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First** you need to get google maps API key for your localhost, this link provides details on how to do that:
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/01/generate-google-maps-api-key-for.html

**Second** in your default.aspx page do this:

**script tags:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC6v5-2uaq_wusHDktM9ILcqIrlPtnZgEk&sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
} else {
alert("Geo Location is not supported on your current browser!");
}
function success(position) {
var lat = position.coords.latitude;
var long = position.coords.longitude;
var city=position.coords.locality;
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
var myOptions = {
center: myLatlng,
zoom: 12,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: myLatlng,
title: "lat: " + lat + " long: " + long
});

marker.setMap(map);
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "<b>User Address</b><br/> Latitude:"+lat+"<br /> Longitude:"+long+"" });
infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
</script>
```

in **body tag** simply include a empty div:

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 800px; height: 500px"></div>
```

**css:**

```
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#map_canvas { height: 100% }
```

**this is the result you should get:**

[image]

**Tutorial:**  http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/01/show-user-current-location-on-google.html

Comment: The position.coords.locality isn't working and returns as undefined.